# automatically reformat docstrings to respect right margin

Tags: pycharm, editor, sublimetext3, docstring

Often I edit a docstring and find my edit pushes a line's width past the desired right margin.  As a result, many lines of text below this edit maybe need be reformatted before my docstring is once again acceptable.
What's a simple and safe way to automatically fix this?

For example:

```
class WellDocumentedClass:
    """The first line of this is <72 characters wide. And is above lots|
    more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.|
    et mauris ac eros placerat auctor. Mauris mollis est scelerisse    |
    accumsan dapibus. Ut imperdiet suscipit lacinia. Maecenas volutpat |
    iaculis malesuada. Sed venenatis ipsum gravida molestolaoreet. Fuse|
    facilisis neque nec mauris maximus rutrum. Suspendisse at vestibulo|
    orci, ut feugiat odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla accumsan justo |
    ligula, at imperdiet quam ultrices non. Cras vitae vehicula ligula.|
    Quisque quam massa, dignissim in volutpat in, mattis eu urna.      |
    """
    pass
```

Oh no! I accidentally omitted the word "docstring" from the first line.  It was so perfectly formatted!

```
class WellDocumentedClass:
    """The first line of this docstring is <72 characters wide. And is |above lots
    more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.|
    et mauris ac eros placerat auctor. Mauris mollis est scelerisse    |
    accumsan dapibus. Ut imperdiet suscipit lacinia. Maecenas volutpat |
    iaculis malesuada. Sed venenatis ipsum gravida molestolaoreet. Fuse|
    facilisis neque nec mauris maximus rutrum. Suspendisse at vestibulo|
    orci, ut feugiat odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla accumsan justo |
    ligula, at imperdiet quam ultrices non. Cras vitae vehicula ligula.|
    Quisque quam massa, dignissim in volutpat in, mattis eu urna.      |
    """
    pass
```

Argh.  Time to use my mouse and press enter a lot... unless... what do you do in moments like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in Sublime Text 3 by creating a (relatively) simple plugin:

- Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin...
- Select all and replace with the following

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import textwrap


class WrapTextCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, width=0):
        # use the narrowest ruler from the view if no width specified, or default to 72 if no rulers are enabled
        width = width or next(iter(self.view.settings().get('rulers', [])), 72)
        new_sel = list()
        # loop through the selections in reverse order so that the selection positions don't move when the selected text changes size
        for sel in reversed(self.view.sel()):
            # make sure the leading indentation is selected, for `dedent` to work properly
            sel = sel.cover(self.view.line(sel.begin()))
            # determine how much indentation is at the first selected line
            indentation_amount = self.view.indentation_level(sel.begin()) * self.view.settings().get('tab_size', 4)
            # create a wrapper that will keep that indentation
            wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(drop_whitespace=True, width=width, initial_indent=' ' * indentation_amount, subsequent_indent=' ' * indentation_amount)
            # unindent the selected text before then reformatting the text to fill the available (column) space
            text = wrapper.fill(textwrap.dedent(self.view.substr(sel)))
            # replace the selected text with the rewrapped text
            self.view.replace(edit, sel, text)
            # resize the selection to match the new wrapped text size
            new_sel.append(sublime.Region(sel.begin(), sel.begin() + len(text)))
        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add_all(new_sel)
```

- save it, in the folder ST recommends (`Packages/User/`) as something like `wraptext.py`
- create a keybinding to invoke the new wrap functionality:

```json
{ "keys": ["alt+."], "command": "wrap_text" },
```

- enjoy

[image: wrap docstring]

Answer (score 2):

In pycharm, mark the docstring and click `Edit -> Fill Paragraph`